# Are there copies of the Iliad in Greek made by Ottomans with pages ordered from right to left?

Tags: ottoman-empire

*This question is indeed more about classic philology than history. Feel free to close if it is not suitable here.*

In the Netflix Turkish series *Rise of Empires: Ottoman* (S2:E4, around minute 10) we see a scene where young Mehmed and Vlad, at that time living together in the royal Ottoman court, open randomly a Greek volume of the Iliad and read it, to divine their future.

It is shown very clearly that young Mehmed opens the volume at the very beginning. Though, the verses he reads are 304-305, book 22: the well known words of Hector before the last duel with Achilles: notoriously something placed towards the end of the poem. Then Vlad does the same, opening the volume at around one third, and reads a verse from book 8. The first part of the same scene is repeated identically with a mature Mehmed, in the last episode.

How is that? Is it (1) just a small inaccuracy?
Or (2) do the director want to suggest that that book was assembled with the pages ordered in the Arabic way?
And the main question:

*Do there exist copies of the Iliad in Greek made by Ottomans with pages ordered from right to left?*

The first, easier explanation does not convince me completely, for it appears that this series, that has some historiography ambition, is in fact extremely accurate especially in every very small detail [maybe to convince that it is also accurate on the large scale, i.e. about its historic judgement and interpretation of facts? This I couldn’t say. Certainly, it is at least a warm celebration of the Ottoman empire]. Costumes, weapons, dates, are always very precise and documented. As to the above scene, we do know that the divination by random opening of books was a common practice, and we do known that the Ottomans actively engaged in the translation and copying of various Greek works, including the Iliad; e.g. we do have the so called Homer Codex (aka Codex Bodleianus A), a copy of the Iliad from XV century.

The page is framed for a second or so; I frozen the image, took a screenshot and zoomed: it is indeed a hand-written Greek copy of the Iliad, opened at the book 22 —yet at verse 232, some 70 verses before the right place, a couple of pages!. With more care, one can even check that the page on the right indeed contains the sequel: thus the books has recto on the right, verso on the left: pages are ordered according to the standard Greek-Latin way.

Comment: This might be better asked on the [Movies and TV SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) since it's essentially about performance and 'stage' management rather than being about history. I'd guess that getting an actor to 'randomly' select the correct page, without making it too obvious, proved a little difficult.

Comment: @KillingTime : but then the actor’s finger points almost exactly the correct verse (an error of 70 verses over more than 15,000). That’s why I wonder if Ottomans did produce copies of Iliad built with pages ordered the opposite way.  If this question is of no interest here I’ll move. it.

Comment: If not random, the actors could perhaps have applied an instinct from reading the Qur'an in Arabic, as a close reference for an ancient work the Ottomans would have read. That would mean simultaneously giving them credit and no credit, though.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "left to right" and not "right to left" (in the Arabic way, as you call it)?

Comment: yes of course ,thank you. fixed.

Comment: You could also ask this on http://latin.stackexchange.com. They take questions about Ancient Greek as well as Latin.